# PHP Daemon with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, nginx, doctrine-orm

I have a PHP daemon running:

```
while (true) {
    $tasks = $this->tasksFinder->findDueTasks();
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        try {
            $handlerClass = $task->getHandlerClass();
            /** @var AbstractTaskHandler $handler */
            $handler = new $handlerClass(...$task->getArguments());
            $handler->setEntityManager($this->getEm());
            $handler->handle();

            $this->getEm()->remove($task);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error("{$e->getMessage()}\n{$e->getTraceAsString()}");

            $task->setDisabled(true);
            $this->getEm()->persist($task);
        }
    }
    $this->getEm()->flush();

    sleep(1);
}
```

Inside of the handler classes (which will be fetched from the daemon) will done some debug work. For example:

```
$this->getEm()->transactional(function (EntityManager $em) {
    $repository = $em->getRepository(UserUnit::class);
    /** @var UserUnit $entity */
    $entity = $repository->findOneBy(['user' => 1, 'type' => Enum::ORC]);
    $em->lock($entity, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    $entity->increase(1);
});
```

So the entry `orc` for player 1 will be increased by one. Imagine we have already 10 orcs. Creating a task and get handled by the daemon results to 11. Everything is fine, but if I set the entry to 0 manually and create a task without restarting the daemon it will be 11 as well. So it seems the daemon is working with a cache!? Am I right? How to solve that? Clearing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Call `$this->getEm()->clear();` after `$this->getEm()->flush();` solved the problem. After calling `clear` the objects will be loaded from the database again instead be served by the identity map of Doctrine.